# Load MP3 or MP4 audio on load

Tags: javascript, html, audio, onload

I want to add an audio of MP3 file as soon as my Page loads (preferably through JS).

1. It should play only once and in the starting
2. I have gone through W3Schools and Mozilla documentations on the `audio` element but it doesn't just work

My HTML:

```html
<audio>
<source src="../html/TaDum.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

My JS:

```js
var vid = document.querySelector("audio"); 
vid.onload = function(){
    vid.play();
};
```

What is the solution here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<audio controls id="audio">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.onload = play();

  function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.play();
  }
</script>
```

Here is a [Demo](https://codepen.io/sasindumaheepala/pen/dyOPMKE)